# Remove similar directories with conditions in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Lets say I have several directories, which are similar but are slightly different at the end:

```
XYZ_e6586_e5984
XYZ_e3282_e5984
XYZ_e9823_e5984
```

Now, in case there are two or more directories whose name is identical except the number between `e` and `_` , only the directories with the highest number should be kept. In this case, `XYZ_e6586_e5984` and `XYZ_e3282_e5984` should be removed.

How do I do that?

Comment: What did you try already? Show us your attempts on solving the problem. Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following those tips.

Comment: With first number I meant i.e. 6586

Answer (score 0):

Simple find regex case here:

```
find /directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype sed -regex "XYZ_e[0-9]\{4}\_e5984 -print0" | sort -nr | tail -n +2 | xargs -i -0 rm -rf "{}"
```

Yet this will only work on linux with GNU find. A more portable but less pretty version is

```
find /directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype sed -regex "XYZ_e[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_e5984" | sort -nr | tail -n +2 | xargs -i rm -rf "{}"
```

Explanation:

Use `-mindepth 1 and -maxdepth 1` to search only direct children of /directory.

`-type -d` specifies only searching for directories.

Regexes are pretty self explanatory in that case.

`-print0` helps to deal with special characters

`sort -nr` sorts the output numericaly from highest to lowest

`tail -n +2` skips first line (ie the highest numbered folder to keep)

`xargs -i rm -rf "{}"` performs the actual deletion (-0 is necessary because of -print0).

Just make sure the sort reverse gets done right (replace `xargs -i rm -rf "{}"` with `echo "xargs -i rm -rf \"{}\""` to show the actual commands that would get executed.

If not sorted right, try **`export LANG=C`** before executing the command.